# salt-ssh : Error appear when trying to cpmile a sls command

Tags: python, python-2.6, salt-stack

this message error appear when i trying to run **test.ping** command :

```
_error:
    Failed to return clean data
retcode:
    10
stderr:
    ERROR: Unable to locate appropriate python command
stdout:
    ERROR: salt requires python 2.6 or newer on target hosts, must have same major version as origin host
```

knowing that the version of python installed in both hosts (master and minion ) is **the same**